# How to do calculations in cypress testing

Tags: node.js, automation, cypress

I need to go through a group of tags that have a specific class associated with them and have  a value

```
    <div class="ratinglabel col-6">
        <label>Area 1: Professional Engagement 
            <span test-data="area_1_Scor">
                (4/16)
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

and i want to find (4/16*5) and save them in var to compare them with another value

i did this :

```
    cy.get('[test-data="area_1_Scor"]', { timeout: 2000 })
    .then(function($ele) {   
      var countOfElements = $ele*5;
      cy.log(countOfElements);
    });
  })
```

and

```
   cy.get('[test-data="area_1_Scor"]').each(($li, index, $lis) => {
      var sum = 0;
      Cypress.$('[test-data="area_1_Scor"]').each(function() {
        sum = +Cypress.$(this).text()*5||0;
      });
      cy.log("Total sum of all span elements:"+sum);
      
      })
```

but log appear as NaN in first case and 0 in second
So how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there (first block), but you need to 1) extract the text from the element and 2) parse the text into numbers

```js
cy.get('[test-data="area_1_Scor"]', { timeout: 2000 })
  .invoke('text')
  .then(text => {
    const numerator = +text.split('/')[0].replace('(', '')
    const denominator = +text.split('/')[1].replace(')', '')
    const countOfElements = numerator * 5 / denominator;
    cy.log(countOfElements);
  });
})
```

Your 2nd block indicates there's multiple elements, if so use `.each()` like this

```js
let sum = 0;
cy.get('[test-data="area_1_Scor"]', {timeout: 2000})
  .each($el => {

    cy.wrap($el).invoke('text')
      .then(text => {
        const numerator = +text.split('/')[0].replace('(', '')
        const denominator = +text.split('/')[1].replace(')', '')
        const countOfElements = numerator * 5 / denominator;
        sum += countOfElements
      }) 
  })
})
.then(() => cy.log(sum))
```

---

**To test the math**

```js
const times5 = (text) => {
  const numerator = +text.split('/')[0].replace('(', '')
  const denominator = +text.split('/')[1].replace(')', '')
  return Math.round(numerator * 5 / denominator)
}

let sum = 0;
cy.get('[test-data="area_1_Scor"]', {timeout: 2000})
  .each($el => {
    cy.wrap($el).invoke('text')
      .then(times5)                   // text is passed in automatically
      .then(result => sum += result)
  })
})
.then(() => cy.log(sum))
```

So you can check the function with

```js
cy.log(times5("(4/16)"))
```

Comment: thanks alot !! thats working :) but i want to ask if i want to take round number from it, for ex : 1.25 becone 1 , 2.7 become 3 how to do that ?

Comment: That's `Math.round(1.25)`, some details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Comment: You may need to play with the math and the rounding (i.e do you round numerator and denominator, or the result). It might be better to separate the math part into a function, I'll add the example.